# Java generic: Unchecked cast

Tags: java

I must use Java 17 (LTS).

The following code works fine, but I have the following warning:

```
Unchecked cast...
```

I am not able to get rid of this warning, whatever I do with my classes.

**The class where the warning appears:**

```
public abstract class Parser<T> {

    protected static <T> Parser<T> build(Class<T> parserType, InputArgGroup arguments) {
        Parser<T> parser;
        if (parserType.isAssignableFrom(Name.class)) {
            parser = (Parser<T>) new NameParser();    <- UNCHECKED CAST: x.NameParser to x.Parser<T>
        } else {
            parser = (Parser<T>) new AddressParser(); <- UNCHECKED CAST: x.AddressParser to x.Parser<T>
        }

        parser.hasTitle(arguments.hasTitle());
        parser.hasHeader(arguments.hasHeader());
        parser.setDateTimePattern(arguments.getDateTimePattern());
        ...
        return parser;
    }

    ... common methods ...

    public abstract List<T> parse(String file);
}
```

**Parser 1:**

```
public class NameParser extends Parser<Name> {
    @Override
    public List<Name> parse(String file) {
        System.out.println("parse name CSV");
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Parser 2:**

```
public class AddressParser extends Parser<Address> {
    @Override
    public List<Address> parse(String file) {
        System.out.println("parse address CSV");
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
public class Aaa {
    public Aaa() {
        var addressParser = Parser.build(Address.class, ...);
        var nameParser = Parser.build(Name.class, ...);

        List<Address> addresses = addressParser.parse("addresses.csv");
        List<Name> names = nameParser.parse("names.csv");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Aaa();
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should check the cast yourself, which you are already doing, to some extent.

Comment: From the type-checker's point of view, there's no guarantee that `NameParser` is returned when `parserType` is `Name`.

Comment: Thx for the hint, but I still do not get it. The code quality checker and IntelliJ IDEA still show the ugly code quality WARNING.

Comment: Yes, because what you are doing is not statically safe. You will need to make sure that you have a unit test which covers all the branches in `build`.

Answer (score 3):

It's only a *warning* to let you know the compiler can't *guarantee* the cast won't fail at runtime. You know it will work, but the compiler isn't sophisticated enough to figure it out too.

Suppress the warning with an annotation.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected static <T> Parser<T> build(Class<T> parserType, InputArgGroup arguments) {
   // ...
}
```

Using this annotation is not circumventing the compiler - you got a warning and after analysis and running tests you verified the cast will never actually fail at runtime. Anyone seeing this annotation should interpret it as a record of your analysis and finding.